# Getting error notices while developing with Django in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I started to use the framework Django on Visual Studio Code, and even though my code is correct and works just fine when I run it, Visual Studio keeps sending error warnings (see pic), which is something that it never does when I don't use the Django framework.

[image]

When I code in Python without using the Django framework and Visual Studio Code signals an error, then there is actually something wrong with my code, but when using Django it seems that it signals errors even tho the code is perfectly fine.

I thought about switching off the feature completely, but it's a very convenient feature, when it works properly.

How can I set Visual Studio Code in a way that when working with Django, it signals errors only when there is actually something wrong with the code?

The errors that VS Code suggests are all related to failed imports. (like the one in the top right corner of the screen) but again, the code works just fine when I run it, so for some reason VS thinks that there could be an error with the import, but it is not the case. Here is one of the error codes that I get, they are all similar and import-related. But again, the code works just fine when I run it on the localhost.

ERROR CODE SAMPLE:

```
{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django_project/django_project/urls.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "import-error",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Unable to import 'django.urls'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 17,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 17,
    "endColumn": 1
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? Can you post them in the question, please?

Comment: Beside `terminal` there is tab called `problems` open it copy one or all of the error messages and paste them in the question instead the image.

Comment: you just need to install the code assistance for django from the visual code extension, or turn of the error notification into the settings.

Comment: You need to copy and paste them, not include them in an image.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Preferences -> Settings

open setting.json, add:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=W,C"],
```

for more details, you can reference: [python_linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting)